# Simplest bijection from circle to "hedgehog"?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $D$ be the unit (closed) disk
$$D=\{(r,\theta)\mid 0\le r\le 1\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$$
and let $H$ be the subset of $D$ consisting only of the rays from the origin with irrational slopes
$$H=\{(r,\theta)\mid \theta\notin\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,2\pi)\}$$
kind of like the "spikes" of a hedgehog.

There is a bijection $D\to H$ because they have the same cardinality but 1) I can't find any and 2) Even If I could, I suspect it wouldn't be simple to describe.

So the question is: can you find a bijection that is easy to describe and preferably "nicest".

I guess the question is equivalent to finding a bijection $[0,2\pi)\to[0,2\pi)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ but can't do that either.

Thanks!

Comment: Does $\theta$ range over $[0,2\pi)$ and you remove only some rational angles, or does $\theta$ range of $[0,1)$ and represents the angle $2\pi \theta$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen edited thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define $f\colon[0,2\pi)\to [0,\pi)\setminus \Bbb Q$ as
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}(x+7)\bmod 2\pi&\text{if }x\equiv a+7b\pmod{2\pi}\text{ for some  }a\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,2\pi), b\in\Bbb N_0\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Note that if $x$ is of the form mentioned, then so is $f(x)$, and only if it is of this from with $b=0$ (and so necessarily $k=0$) it is not $f(x')$ for some other $x'$.